# attachments saved on a folder is getting mixed with other attachments saved on different folder

Tags: java, spring-mvc

So my project consists of workflow for every request generated a unique request id eg.FAF/2020-21/0253 is getting generated and folder of the name 0253 is created on mentioned path on server and attachment is saved in the format eg(ISAMEA Certificate print_Req_576_010720_111908.xlsx).so the issue is that
sometimes attachment saved on one folder gets added to other folder as well.

private void uploadAttachmentToDiskAttach(FinancialApprovalBean fab, String genetaredId, String strLoginUserId,
String role) {

```
`path on server where attachment is getting saved`
    String rootPath = "/data/PamGreenSource/Documents/" + genetaredId;
    FinancialAttachmentBean fabc = new FinancialAttachmentBean();
    /*Documents document = new Documents();*/
    if ( fab.getFab().size() > 0) {
        for (int i=0;i<fab.getFab().size();i++) {
            if (fab.getFab().get(i).getFiles() != null) {
                String orgName = fab.getFab().get(i).getFiles().getOriginalFilename();
                
                File theDir = new File(rootPath);

                
                if (!theDir.exists()) {
                    boolean result = false;
                    try {
                        theDir.mkdirs();
                        result = true;
                    } catch (SecurityException se) {
                    }
                    if (result) {
                    }
                }

                String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy_Hmmss").format(new Date());

                String fileNameWithOutExt = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(orgName);
                
                if (fileNameWithOutExt != null && !fileNameWithOutExt.isEmpty()) {
                    fileNameWithOutExt = fileNameWithOutExt + "_" + role + "_" + strLoginUserId + "_" + timestamp;
                    String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(orgName);
                    fab.getFab().get(i).setAttach_id(fileNameWithOutExt+"."+extension);
                    String filePath = rootPath + "/" + fileNameWithOutExt + "." + extension;
                    File dest = new File(filePath);
                    try {
                        fab.getFab().get(i).getFiles().transferTo(dest);
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    
}**strong text**
```